# Syntax error when I use rigidbody2D.velocity.y

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, syntax-error

I'm writing my first game, and the code that teaches my character to jump. I met this error "rigidbody2D.velocity.y" and "rigidbody2D.AddForce" is underlined in red and I can't understand why.

My code:

```
private bool isGrounded = false;
public Transform groundCheck;
private float groundRadius = 0.2f;
public LayerMask whatIsGround;
private Animator anim;

private void Start()
{
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    isGrounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, groundRadius, whatIsGround);

    anim.SetBool("Ground", isGrounded);
    anim.SetFloat("vSpeed", rigidbody2D.velocity.y);

    if (!isGrounded)
        return;
}


private void Update()
{
    if (isGrounded && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        anim.SetBool("Ground", false);
        rigidbody2D.AddForce(new Vector2(0, 600));
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the datatype of `rigidbody2D`. Is it initialized anywhere?

Comment: Please provide the error hint that IDE shows when you hover on red underlined code.

Comment: the error was solved, thanks to all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Game Object` must have a `Rigidbody2D` *component* and you should first get `Rigidbody2D` *component* in `start method`:

```
...
private Rigidbody2D rigidbody2D;

void Start()
{
    ...
    rigidbody2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}
```

then access to Rigidbody2D properties.

edited code:

```
private bool isGrounded = false;
public Transform groundCheck;
private float groundRadius = 0.2f;
public LayerMask whatIsGround;
private Animator anim;
private Rigidbody2D rigidbody2D;

private void Start()
{
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    rigidbody2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    isGrounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, groundRadius, whatIsGround);

    anim.SetBool("Ground", isGrounded);
    anim.SetFloat("vSpeed", rigidbody2D.velocity.y);

    if (!isGrounded)
        return;
}


private void Update()
{
    if (isGrounded && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        anim.SetBool("Ground", false);
        rigidbody2D.AddForce(new Vector2(0, 600));
    }
}
```

Comment: right? file:///C:/Users/zerir/Desktop/materials/%D0%A1sd%D0%BA.PNG

Comment: it was a screenshot

Comment: how? i nobe....

Comment: unit appears and disappears slice

Comment: I think I need more reputation